# Index was outside the bounds of the array shown when date retrieve from database

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net

```
dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime((sdr[1]),   
                        CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
```

I am pulling a date value from a SqlDataReader, but reading it results in an error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Physio_cure_Search", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;   
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RegisterNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtsearch.Text;    
SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
while (sdr.Read())
{
    txtregistrationno.Text = sdr.GetString(0);
    //giving error on this line:    
    dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime((sdr[1]), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);        
}
```

Here `sdr` is instance of `SqlDataReader` and sdr[1] is used to retrieve database value.
How can this be fixed?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Physio_cure_Search]
@RegisterNo varchar(500)   
As
begin
    select Convert(varchar(100),DateOfBirth,103) as DateOfBirth 
    from Physio_cureTable

    select RegisterNo,RegistrationDate,Stimulation,PationName,DateOfBirth,ContactNo,Occupation,Age,
    Sex,Weight,Chief_Complain,Investigation_Result,PastHistoryAny,Physical_Examination,Ref_By_Doctor,Medications,Prognosis,Electro_Therapy,Neuro_Rehabilitation,Ortho_Rehabilitation,Cardio_Pulmonery_Rehabilitation,Sports_Rehabilitation 

    from Physio_cureTable where RegisterNo=@RegisterNo and Syncoperation <>'D'
end
```

Comment: sdr is the object of sql data reader

Comment: now p.cambell sir im editing question

Comment: Could you add your stored procedure code?

Comment: store procedure added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems: your stored procedure is returning 2 resultsets, and you're operating on the first one. Secondly, your C# code won't work.

1- **Remove the first resultset**:  `select Convert(varchar(100),DateOfBirth,103) as DateOfBirth 
    from Physio_cureTable`. This is useless to your C# code.

2- Modify your code to explicitly **retrieve values by column name, and not by numeric index**.

```
 while (sdr.Read())
 {
     txtReg.Text = sdr["RegisterNo"].ToString();
     dateTimePicker2.Value = 
         Convert.ToDateTime(sdr["RegistrationDate"].ToString(),   
                            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
 }
```

3- Remove all unused columns from your select statement, if this stored proc is only being used by this calling code.

```
select  RegisterNo, RegistrationDate
from Physio_cureTable where RegisterNo=@RegisterNo and Syncoperation <>'D'
```